# How to install tool `xmltodict`?

Tags: pip, apt

Using ubuntu 20.04.5 I am trying to install the tool [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) as follows:

```
$ pip install xmltodict
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/dhcrypto.py:15: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/util.py:19: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting xmltodict
  Using cached xmltodict-0.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)
Installing collected packages: xmltodict
Successfully installed xmltodict-0.13.0
```

But when I try to use this tool as follows

```
cat run.tcx | xmltodict 2
```

I get an error

```
xmltodict: command not found
```

I already uninstalled and tried to re-install, but same issue. I also have no alias defined with the same name, and `which xmltodict` returns nothing.

Installing it via

```
sudo apt install python-xmltodict
```

also does not seem to install it.

What could be wrong this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package doesn't install any scripts or entry points. It only [installs](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/blob/fe3a37571e3867845b29e3c14ccc88186cbe379d/setup.py#L42) an importable module `xmltodict.py`. The module seems to be runnable but not directly executable so try [`python -m xmltodict`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m):

```
cat run.tcx | python -m xmltodict 2
```

Comment: Ok I see. But this is not really visible from the documentation. And what does the number "2" mean?

Comment: "*…this is not really visible from the documentation.*" This means the documentation is not that great. You can help the authors by submitting a pull request. "*And what does the number "2" mean?*" I copied it from your question; you've said above `cat run.tcx | xmltodict 2` <- **2**

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks. I will continue from here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using python3.x, try using

```
sudo apt install python3-xmltodict
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `which xmltodict` still returns nothing, and calling `xmltodict` alone leads again to the error `xmltodict: command not found`.

Comment: Can you confirm that it's installed on your system? You can do this for example by using the `mlocate` package `sudo locate xmltodict` or `sudo locate python3-xmltodict` (or whatever it is called)

Comment: It seems to be installed as part of other, older virtualenvs, but not in common folders like `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local` or something like that. 
Maybe my system is broken?

Comment: A file `xmltodict.py` is located under `/home/adietz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, but no executable under `/home/adietz/.local/bin/`

Comment: What is your systems default python version `python --version` ?

Comment: python version is 3.8.10